# Redshift: ISO Reporting Week with YoY - how to filter the dates without hard coding or calendar tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In business operational contexts a very common time interval for reporting is weekly aggregates compared to the ***same financial reporting week*** Year-on-Year. I'm using ISO reporting week numbers and reporting week is Sunday through Saturday.

**I would like to accomplish this with a where clause filter, and not joining to a calendar table, which is generally beyond the scope of casual SQL users.**

This is difficult when there are 53 reporting weeks in an adjacent year, because the reporting weeks don't line up after subtracting 52 weeks.

For example, consider this typical idiom where getting prior year dates will cause problems:

```
  select ...
           /* must be saturday run_date!!! */
  where    activity_day between job_run_date - 6 - 52*7
                            and job_run_date - 52*7
```

#### "What problem with YoY comparisons when subtracting by 52 weeks," you ask?

Let's consider the first reporting week of 2016, which ends on saturday Jan 9th:

```
  => \! cal jan 2016
      January 2016
  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                  1  2
   3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
  17 18 19 20 21 22 23
  24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  31

  select      '2016-01-09'  weekend
              , to_char('2016-01-09'::date       ,'iyyy-iw')  CY_reporting_week
              , to_char('2016-01-09'::date - 7*52,'iyyy-iw')  PY_reporting_week
  ;
  ┌────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
  │  weekend   │ cy_reporting_week │ py_reporting_week │
  ├────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┤
  │ 2016-01-09 │ 2016-01           │ 2015-02           │
  └────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Oh no, what happened? Year 2015 has 53 reporting weeks, so subtracting 52 weeks doesn't give the YoY comparison you were hoping for. Not to worry, it all works out once you make it to 2017...

```
  select      weekend
              , to_char(weekend,'iyyy-iw')  CY_reporting_week
              , to_char(weekend - 7*52,'iyyy-iw')  PY_reporting_week

  from        (select '2016-01-09' + generate_series(-21,364,7)  weekend);

  ┌────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
  │  weekend   │ cy_reporting_week │ py_reporting_week │
  ├────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┤
  │ 2015-12-19 │ 2015-51           │ 2014-51           │
  │ 2015-12-26 │ 2015-52           │ 2014-52           │
  │ 2016-01-02 │ 2015-53           │ 2015-01           │
  │ 2016-01-09 │ 2016-01           │ 2015-02           │ <--- these are not
  │ 2016-01-16 │ 2016-02           │ 2015-03           │  --  the YoY comparisons
  │ 2016-01-23 │ 2016-03           │ 2015-04           │  --  you were looking for.
  ...
  │ 2016-12-17 │ 2016-50           │ 2015-51           │
  │ 2016-12-24 │ 2016-51           │ 2015-52           │
  │ 2016-12-31 │ 2016-52           │ 2015-53           │
  │ 2017-01-07 │ 2017-01           │ 2016-01           │
  └────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A calendar table is the best way to do this,* but I want a solution that business users can copy/paste rather than learn about calendar tables and manage the join.

Here is the tested solution for posterity. This works properly for any chosen **job_run_date** it will select the most recent prior saturday as the ending day of the reporting week, or current saturday if **job_run_date** is a saturday:

```
  where   (  /* prior year current reporting week */
      activity_day between 
          to_date(
              (to_char(job_run_date + 1 - 7 + 1, 'iyyy') - 1)
              || '-' 
              || to_char(job_run_date + 1 - 7 + 1, 'iw')
              ,'iyyy-iw'
              ) - 1
          and 
          next_day(to_date(
              (to_char(job_run_date + 1 - 7 + 1, 'iyyy') - 1)
              || '-' 
              || to_char(job_run_date + 1 - 7 + 1, 'iw')
              ,'iyyy-iw'
              ), 'sat')

      or

      /* current reporting week */
      activity_day between 
          next_day(job_run_date - 7 * 2, 'sat') + 1
          and 
          next_day(job_run_date - 7, 'sat')
  )
```

We avoid transforming the date field into reporting week form to make a predicate comparison. Although it makes the comparison syntax easy, the engine would have to make a full table scan without the benefit of indexes and partitions on the date field:

```
  /* this is crap */
  where       to_char(activity_day + 1,'iyyy') in (to_char(next_day(job_run_date - 1 - 7, 'sat'),'iyyy') - 1
                                            ,to_char(next_day(job_run_date - 1 - 7, 'sat'),'iyyy'))
  and         to_char(activity_day + 1,'iw') = to_char(next_day(job_run_date - 1 - 7, 'sat'),'iw')
```

Our solution will rebuild the dates bracketing the reporting weeks by:

- computing the current reporting week in form `YYYY-WW'
- subtracting 1 from the current year
- combining the strings for (YYYY - 1) and "-" and WW
- computing the begining and end dates for the reporting week

There's no way to completely escape the week 53 oddity, here is what happens using the above idiom:

When you get to week 53 of your reporting year, the YoY comparison matches to week 1 of the same year. For example 2015 had 53 reporting weeks, but 2014 did not. When comparing YoY of reporting week `2015-53` you get `2014-53` which `to_date` will translate to a date in the reporting week `2015-01`. Not unreasonable, better than comparing to a null reporting week.

The one remaining oddity is that when you get to the following year, you'll never use the prior year's week 53 as a baseline comparison, because no consecutive ISO reporting years have 53 reporting weeks. Correspondingly, ISO week `2015-01` will be used as the basis for YoY comparisons to `2015-53` and `2016-01`.

"I can live with that." - Special Agent Johnson

```
  select  '2016-01-02' weekend
          , to_char('2016-01-02'::date,'iyyy-iw') reporting_week
          , to_date('2014-53','iyyy-iw') + 5  PY_weekend
          , to_char('2015-01-03'::date,'iyyy-iw')  PY_reporting_week
  ;
  ┌────────────┬────────────────┬────────────┬───────────────────┐
  │  weekend   │ reporting_week │ py_weekend │ py_reporting_week │
  ├────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
  │ 2016-01-02 │ 2015-53        │ 2015-01-03 │ 2015-01           │
  └────────────┴────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┘
```